# Inno Setup - Match the language of the installation with the system language and default to English

Tags: inno-setup

I want that, when the user execute the installer, the language is defined by the system language. But in this way:

System language: Spanish - installer in Spanish

System language: any other language - installer in English

Is this possible?

Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quoting [Inno Setup documentation on Languages section](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=languagessection) (emphasis mine):

> Setup determines the default language to use for its messages in the following order:
>
> ...
>
> Unicode Inno Setup:
>
> - It searches for a language whose `LanguageID` setting (normally specified in the [LangOptions] section of the language's .isl file) matches both the primary language identifier and sublanguage identifier of the current user's UI language or locale (depending on the setting of LanguageDetectionMethod).
> - ...
> - **If no match is found, it defaults to the first language specified in the [Languages] section.**

---

So all you need to do, is to put English first. And keep `LanguageDetectionMethod` to its default value of `uilanguage`.